# How can I hide a menu item, without breaking its route?

Tags: joomla-3.x, menu

How can I hide a menu item, without breaking its route?

I would like to have an example.com/hiddenpage route that goes to a single article, but I don’t want the hiddenpage to be visible anywhere in the menu system.

Answer (score 4):

Simply create Hidden Menu (call it whatever you want) which is not to be used in any menu module. It will hold menu items not visible on front end, and put your menu item in it.

Comment: I do this for Login with every site I build.

Comment: This is very useful too when you need control differents modules to show in specific link